# iMac 15.1 2012 Target Disk problem

Tags: imac, target-disk-mode

On my iMac 15.1 from 2012 with Big Sur I wanted to startup from another USB-disk. The normal procedure with the Option key did not work so I tried using a Target Disk. That looks like trouble.
After reboot the screen is just black with a lock and an input field. Connecting to my recent Ventura laptop via cable does not help.
With a wired keyboard and wired mouse I can typ some text in the input field, but there is no reaction.
How can I leave the Target Disk mode?

Comment: Reads like a firmware password has been set? https://support.apple.com/HT204156#firmware

Comment: "How can I leave the Target Disk mode?" - On the Mac you used as a disk, push the power button to shut it down, then disconnect the cable. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac

Comment: Thank you Redarm. It was indeed a firmware password set in the past, but I found it.